# Concern with CHECK TABLE on large InnoDB 24x7 table,

Tags: innodb

Will CHECK TABLE on large InnoDb table causing issue with blocking of online transactions? Assuming the table size is 5GB.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MySQL BOL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/check-table.html#check-table-innodb), CHECK TABLE blocks other threads on the table.

> When running CHECK TABLE on large InnoDB tables, other threads may be
>   blocked during CHECK TABLE execution. To avoid timeouts, the semaphore
>   wait threshold (600 seconds) is extended by 2 hours (7200 seconds) for
>   CHECK TABLE operations. If InnoDB detects semaphore waits of 240
>   seconds or more, it starts printing InnoDB monitor output to the error
>   log. If a lock request extends beyond the semaphore wait threshold,
>   InnoDB aborts the process. To avoid the possibility of a semaphore
>   wait timeout entirely, run CHECK TABLE QUICK instead of CHECK TABLE.

Thanks!